# Is there way to define return type inside the body of function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, return, return-value, return-type

How i can define return type inside function at run-time? I have a member **char* m_data;** and I want to return a conversion of m_data into different types in different cases.

```
?type? getData() const
{
    switch(this->p_header->WAVE_F.bitsPerSample)
    {
        case 8:
        {
            // return type const char *
            break;
        }
        case 16:
        {
            // return type const short *
            break;
        }
        case 32:
        {
            // return type const int *
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the caller always know which data type will be returned? If not, how will you call the function?

Comment: You could return `void *` and cast when you access the result.

Comment: actually the better way would to create an `iterator` which would get the "stepsize" dynamically assigned from `bitsPerSample` and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but as you always return a pointer you could just return a `void*`. Beware the caller would have no option to figure out what is behind the pointer, so you better try to wrap the return value in `boost::variant<char*,short*,int*>` or `boost::any`/`cdiggins::any`

Comment: The caller still has to know which type to extract, using `boost::variant<>`/`boost::any` or `void*`, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @hauzer: at least with `variant` or `any`, the caller only has to *suspect* what the type is, and if they're wrong they can find out dynamically (hence they can make several attempts, or with `variant` they can use `which()` or `apply_visitor`). With `void*` they actually have to *know* :-)

Answer (score 2):

Make a getter for `bitsPerSample` and let the caller choose one of the appropriate methods:

```
int getBitsPerSample(){
    return p_header->WAVE_F.bitsPerSample;
}

const char* getDataAsCharPtr() {
    // return type const char *
}

const short* getDataAsShortPtr() {
    // return type const short *
}

const int* getDataAsIntPtr() {
    // return type const int *
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, I suggest to use something like :

```
const char* getDataAsChar() const
{
    if (this->p_header->WAVE_F.bitsPerSample != 8) return nullptr;
    //return data as const char*
}

const short* getDataAsShort() const
{
    if (this->p_header->WAVE_F.bitsPerSample != 16) return nullptr;
    //return data as const short*
}

const int* getDataAsInt() const
{
    if (this->p_header->WAVE_F.bitsPerSample != 32) return nullptr;
    //return data as const int*
}
```